# "Inconsistent Audio Classification Results between Flutter App and Postman - Flask API"

Tags: python, flutter, flask, librosa

I've developed a Flutter app that records audio and sends it to a Python Flask API for classification. The API uses Librosa for feature extraction and a pre-trained ML model for audio classification. However, I'm experiencing inconsistencies in the predictions.

#### Problem:

- When I send audio files from the Flutter app to the Flask API, I get incorrect classifications but when use Postman to send an audio file that was recorded with the same app I used for collecting training data, the classification is correct.
- Both recordings are in `.wav` format with a bit rate of 16 kHz.

**code**

```
Future<void> _startRecording() async {
    try {
      Record record = Record();
      if (await record.hasPermission()) {
        print("startRecording() hasPermission ");
        Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        String tempPath = tempDir.path + '/audio.wav';
        await record.start(path: tempPath);
        setState(() {
          _isRecording = true;
          _audioPath = tempPath;
          print("tempPath $tempPath");
        });
        print("Start Recording - _audioPath: $_audioPath");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("startRecording() has no Permission");
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stopRecording() async {
    try {
      Record record = Record();
      String? path = await record.stop();
      if (path != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isRecording = false;
          _audioPath = path;
        }); // Call the upload method here
        print("Stop Recording - _audioPath: $_audioPath");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      uploadAudio(File(_audioPath!), 'balla');
    });
  }

  Future<void> uploadAudio(File audioFile, String inputWord) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://192.168.8.181:5000/predict'));
    request.fields['input_word'] = inputWord;
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('audio_file', await audioFile.readAsBytes(), filename: 'audio.wav'));

    var response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
      print('Result: ${result.body}');
      var parsedJson = json.decode(result.body);
      if (parsedJson['result'] == "Correct Answer") {
        audioPlayer.dispose();  audioPlayer.pause();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Correct(),
          ),
        );
      }
      if (parsedJson['result'] == "Wrong Answer") {
        audioPlayer.dispose();  audioPlayer.pause();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => InCorrect(),
          ),
        );
      }

    } else {
      print('Failed to upload audio');
    }
  }
```

**Flask API**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os
import librosa
import numpy as np
import joblib
import subprocess
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

# Initialize logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.INFO)

# Define max_length
max_length = 100


# Function to convert audio file bit rate
def convert_audio_bit_rate(audio_file_path, target_bit_rate=256000):
    output_file_path = "converted_audio.wav"
    try:
        # Delete the existing converted file if it exists
        if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
            os.remove(output_file_path)

        subprocess.run([
            "ffmpeg",
            "-i", audio_file_path,
            "-ab", str(target_bit_rate),
            output_file_path
        ])
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in converting audio: {e}")
        return None
    return output_file_path


def predict_class(audio_file_path):
    try:
        # Load the scaler, label encoder, and the model
        scaler = joblib.load('scaler.pkl')
        le = joblib.load('label_encoder.pkl')
        model = joblib.load('Student_audio_model.pkl')

        # Load the audio file
        waveform, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_file_path, sr=None)

        # Feature extraction
        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=waveform, sr=sample_rate)

        # Padding feature array to a fixed length
        if mfcc.shape[1] < max_length:
            pad_width = max_length - mfcc.shape[1]
            mfcc = np.pad(mfcc, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)), mode='constant')
        else:
            mfcc = mfcc[:, :max_length]

        # Reshaping and scaling
        features = mfcc.reshape(1, -1)
        features = scaler.transform(features)

        # Prediction
        predicted_class = model.predict(features)

        # Convert integer label to original class label
        predicted_label = le.inverse_transform(predicted_class)[0]

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in prediction: {e}")
        return None

    return predicted_label


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        # Get the audio file
        audio_file = request.files["audio_file"]

        # Save the audio file
        audio_file_path = "uploaded_audio.wav"
        audio_file.save(audio_file_path)

        # Predict the class
        predicted_class = predict_class(audio_file_path)
        if predicted_class is None:
            return jsonify({"result": "Error in prediction"}), 500

        # Get the input_word
        input_word = request.form["input_word"]

        # Clean-up
       # if os.path.exists(audio_file_path):
          #  os.remove(audio_file_path)
        #if os.path.exists(converted_audio_file_path):
           # os.remove(converted_audio_file_path)

        if input_word == predicted_class:
            return jsonify({"result": "Correct Answer"})
        else:
            return jsonify({"result": "Wrong Answer"})

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"General error: {e}")
        return jsonify({"result": "An error occurred"}), 500


@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return jsonify({"error": "Not Found"}), 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    return jsonify({"error": "Internal Server Error"}), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

How i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your training data is 16 KHz, but I'd double check that. For example your code contains `convert_audio_bit_rate()` with the bitrate of 256 kbps. What is that method for? If you wanted to convert the data before use (i.e. in `predict()`) then you apparently forgot.

BTW: if you want to use `convert_audio_bit_rate()`, then note the current implementation uses fixed value `output_file_path = "converted_audio.wav"` as write target, which will cause problems when you get multiple simultaneous requests.